# Does IntelliJ support something like VS Debugger Visualizers?

Tags: intellij-idea, debuggervisualizer

I would like to see the contents of a certain `Enumeration<T>` instance. In the absence of a List/Array like type accepting it in its constructor another viable option would be a Debugger Visualizer, something that exists in VS.

How can I do it in IntelliJ?

Comment: Data Type Renderers? http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debugger-data-type-renderers.html

Comment: Precisely. Please, arrange your comment as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has [Data Type Renderers](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debugger-data-type-renderers.html) for the debugger:

> IntelliJ IDEA allows you to specify how different objects are
>   displayed in the debugger on a class-by-class basis. You can assign
>   expressions to display rather than rely on the object's String
>   representation.
>
> For example, if an object represents a user, you may want to see users
>   represented by their login name; or, for a cache entry object, its age
>   and contents may be appropriate. IntelliJ IDEA refers to these as type
>   renderers.

Comment: Although, I do not see an option to load a third party jar implementing a complex renderer.

Comment: It should be in a project classpath.

Comment: But where do I mention the renderers type? The documentation does not mention that a custom renderer is even supported.

Comment: You can google several examples, like this one: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/04/type-renderers/

Comment: You misunderstand me. Your example shows how to render a custom type using the default facilities provided by IntelliJ. I am talking about how to render a customer type using a **custom renderer**! In VS you can return a proxy object instead of the original one, which would be displayed in the debugger. For instance, if I wanted to display a binary tree as a flat list - I can do so. Expanding a tree object in the watch window will show the respective flat list. Can I do this in IntelliJ?

Comment: In the **Expression** field you can use your own classes, something like `new foo.MyProxy(this)` will work if `MyProxy` accepts the type of the object you want to render and defines custom `toString()`. It's also possible to use static methods provided by your project classes: `foo.MyRenderer.render(this)`.

Comment: Unlike VS Studio, it can't support image and visualisations not based on texts

Comment: Note: IntelliJ can show `BufferedImage` (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712312/is-it-possible-to-watch-bufferedimage-objects-while-debugging-in-intellij), therefore you might be able to render some debugging images in your program with some effort (I am afraid you will not be able to provide this debugger-side unfortunately)