# Is it possible to watch BufferedImage objects while debugging in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, visualization

Is it possible to watch BufferedImage objects while debugging in IntelliJ?

I mean to view visual content of an image, not memory identity.

Is it also possible to view custom objects visually, i.e. write some custom visualizers?

Answer (score 9):

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1 is able to display `BufferedImage` object as image while debugging by default (probabily previous versions also support this feature).

1. Set up a breakpoint where you can access the `BufferedImage` object
2. By default, for `BufferedImage` class Idea will set *Image* viewer, so you can simply click on the *View image* text in the row of the `BufferedImage` object in the debugger window, on the very right hand side. This is also available in the *Evaluate Expression* window.
   [image: Image viewer while debugging in IDEA]
3. In case another viewer is set for the `BufferedImage` class, you can change it back by right clicking on the `BufferedImage` object in the debugger window, and select *View as / Image*.

The image will be loaded in a popup window. (You can resize the the popup, but cannot move. I'm on OS X, the window handling of Idea is a bit weird here, maybe better on Win)

---

You can also create your own object visualizers. This can also be done in the *View as* context menu, in this case choose the *Create...* option.
There you can enter your custom expression, which will be displayed in the row of the object in the debugger window. Please note that this is for displaying information of the object in text format only.

For example if you want to display the `BufferedImage` as `[width]x[height]` in the debugger window, create a new view, select *Use following expression* radio button, and enter the following expression:

```
getWidth() + "x" + getHeight()
```

[image]

After clicking *Apply* or *OK*, you will get:
[image]

You can manage your viewers by right clicking in the *Variables* or *Watches* panel, and select *Customize Data Views...*

Comment: WOW! That's super cool! And just what I needed. I clicked the "show image" and I'm golden :-)